# snapshot by glReadPixels. Then flip the pixels content. But the image quality has been decreased

Tags: opengl-es, snapshot

All. 
Now I am using unity3D to develop the game. And I want to save the content of each frame by AVFoundation as mp4 file. But I met some problem while I process the snapshot. After I use glReadPixels to obtain the data saved in render buffer, vertex shader and fragment shader is used to help me turn update side down the pixels content. But, after flipping each frame, I found that the quality of each frame has been decreased a lot. So, anyone has met this kind of case before. 
Here is the code related. 
The snapshot part,

```
- (void *)snapshot
{
//    NSLog(@"snapshot used here");
    GLint backingWidth1, backingHeight1;
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, mainDisplaySurface->systemColorRB);
// Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth1);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight1);



    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth1, height = backingHeight1;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));
    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    if (transformData == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"transformData initial");
        transformData = new loadDataFromeX();
        transformData->setupOGL(backingWidth1, backingHeight1);
    }

    NSLog(@"data %d, %d, %d", (int)data[0], (int)data[1], (int)data[2]);

    transformData->drawingOGL(data);
    return data;
```

}

Here, transformData is an c++ class to help me to the flipping work. 
in the function, setOGL(), all the textures and framebuffers have been constructed. 
in the function drawingOGL(), the flipping work has been done by passing through the vertex shader and fragment shader. The details of this function is listed below,

```
int loadDataFromeX::drawingOGL(unsigned char* data)
{

    //load data to the texture;
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER ,transFBO.frameBuffer);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1., 0., 0., 1.);
    glViewport(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);


    GLfloat vertex_postions[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, -10.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, -10.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, -10.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, -10.0f
   };

    GLfloat texture_coords[] = {    //left up corner is (0.0)
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
};

   glUseProgram(gl_program_id);

   glVertexAttribPointer(gl_attribute_position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,vertex_postions);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(gl_attribute_position);

   glVertexAttribPointer(gl_attribute_texture_coordinate, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,texture_coords);
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(gl_attribute_texture_coordinate);

// Load textures

   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);


   if(flag)
   {
      flag = false;
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
   }
   else
   {
       glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
   }

   glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_id, "inputImageTexture"), 0);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

   glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpLocation, 1, 0, gComputeMVP);

   glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP ,0 ,4);
   glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
   glReadPixels(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);


   glFinish();
   cout<<"data: "<<(int)data[0]<<"; "<<(int)data[1]<<", "<<(int)data[2]<<endl;

   return 1;
```

}

The vertex shader ans fragment shader have been provided below,

```
static float l = -1.f,   r =  1.f;
static float b = -1.f,   t =  1.f;
static float n =  0.1f,  f =  100.f;
static float gComputeMVP[16] = {
2.0f/(r-l),    0.0f,          0.0f,         0.0f,
0.0f,          2.0f/(t-b),    0.0f,         0.0f,
0.0f,          0.0f,         -2.0f/(f-n),   0.0f,
-(r+l)/(r-l),  -(t+b)/(t-b),  -(f+n)/(f-n),  1.0f
};

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertex_shader_str =
"attribute vec4 position;\n"
"attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;\n"
"varying mediump vec2 textureCoordinate;\n"
"uniform mat4  mvpMatrix;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"    gl_Position = position;\n"
"    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * position;\n"
"    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;\n"
"}";

const char* fragment_shader_str = ""
" varying mediump vec2 textureCoordinate;\n"
"\n"
" uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n"
" \n"
" void main()\n"
" {\n"
"   mediump vec4 Color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);\n"
"   gl_FragColor = vec4(Color.z, Color.y, Color.x, Color.w);\n"
" }";
```

I don't know why the quality of each frame has been decreased. And also, when I compare the output of variable, data, before and after using drawingOGL, as these two lines shown below,

```
cout<<"data: "<<(int)data[0]<<"; "<<(int)data[1]<<", "<<(int)data[2]<<endl;

NSLog(@"data %d, %d, %d", (int)data[0], (int)data[1], (int)data[2]);
```

The first line gave the right pixel value. But, the second line always gave ZERO. It's really strange, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the reason to this strange problem. It was caused by the context of unity3D. I'm not familiar with unity3d. So, maybe, only someone like me will do something stupid like this. There is some special setting related with OpenGL ES in the context, belonging to unity3d. So, in order to finish the task in snapshot, a new context has to be established and only activate it when the snapshot is working.

In order to solve the problem, I construct an individual context (EAGLContext*) for the snapshot task like this,

```
- (void *)snapshot
{
    //    NSLog(@"snapshot used here");
    GLint backingWidth1, backingHeight1;
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, mainDisplaySurface->systemColorRB);
// Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth1);
  glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight1);


NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth1, height = backingHeight1;
NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));
// Read pixel data from the framebuffer
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
NSLog(@"data %d, %d, %d", (int)data[0], (int)data[1], (int)data[2]);
NSLog(@"backingWidth1 : %d, backingHeight1: %d", backingWidth1, backingHeight1);

if (transformData == NULL)
{
    mycontext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: mycontext];

    NSLog(@"transformData initial");
    transformData = new loadDataFromeX();
    transformData->setupOGL(backingWidth1, backingHeight1);
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: mainDisplaySurface->context];
}


{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: mycontext];
    transformData->drawingOGL(data);
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: mainDisplaySurface->context];
}
}
```

When the resources used for snapshot is to be released, the codes is written like this,

```
if (transformData != NULL)
{
    {
         [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: mycontext];   
         transformData->destroy();
         delete transformData;
         transformData = NULL;   
         [EAGLContext setCurrentContext: mainDisplaySurface->context];
     }

     [mycontext release];
     mycontext = nil;
 }
```